# How get rid from App getting crashed on launch?

Tags: android, android-studio, multi-index

Crashing app when launching,
Update Gradle plugin 4.x.x to 7.0.4 and Migrate Dagger2 to Hilt.
And update Kotlin to 1.6.0.
Added `@@HiltAndroidApp` on the Application class.
Apply Multidex but not working.
Try some other solutions but not helped.

Please see the log.

```
tech.xyz.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: tech.xyz.android, PID: 14295
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application tech.xyz.android.base.BaseApplication package tech.xyz.android: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "tech.xyz.android.base.BaseApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~GzEkuyUrT68SI_tbzjNEGg==/tech.xyz.android-puNWBMfhZZkc5IKFz18ZHA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~GzEkuyUrT68SI_tbzjNEGg==/tech.xyz.android-puNWBMfhZZkc5IKFz18ZHA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~GzEkuyUrT68SI_tbzjNEGg==/tech.xyz.android-puNWBMfhZZkc5IKFz18ZHA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64, /product/lib64]]
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1364)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6689)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:247)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2057)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "tech.xyz.android.base.BaseApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~GzEkuyUrT68SI_tbzjNEGg==/tech.xyz.android-puNWBMfhZZkc5IKFz18ZHA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~GzEkuyUrT68SI_tbzjNEGg==/tech.xyz.android-puNWBMfhZZkc5IKFz18ZHA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~GzEkuyUrT68SI_tbzjNEGg==/tech.xyz.android-puNWBMfhZZkc5IKFz18ZHA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64, /product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:52)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1177)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1356)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6689) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:247) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2057) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ltech/xyz/android/base/Hilt_BaseApplication;
        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
                ... 15 more
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "tech.xyz.android.base.Hilt_BaseApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~GzEkuyUrT68SI_tbzjNEGg==/tech.xyz.android-puNWBMfhZZkc5IKFz18ZHA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~GzEkuyUrT68SI_tbzjNEGg==/tech.xyz.android-puNWBMfhZZkc5IKFz18ZHA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~GzEkuyUrT68SI_tbzjNEGg==/tech.xyz.android-puNWBMfhZZkc5IKFz18ZHA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64, /product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                ... 18 more
```

After update gradle, kotlin and add hilt into root-level Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext{
        kotlin_version = "1.6.0"
        apollo_version = '2.5.10'
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.40.5'
        classpath "com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-gradle-plugin:$apollo_version"
    }
}

allprojects {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is the Application class:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class BaseApplication : Application(), LifecycleObserver {
    private val TAG = "BaseApplication"
    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: BaseApplication
            private set
    }

    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context?) {
//        MultiDex.install(base)
        super.attachBaseContext(base)
    }
    override fun onCreate() {
        ActivityLifecycleCallback.register(this)
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
        userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(this, "AdaptiveExoplayer")
        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(!BuildConfig.DEBUG)

        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get()
            .lifecycle
            .addObserver(this)
    }
}
```

Here is the `<application>` tag of `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:name=".base.BaseApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_config"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

Most of the solutions say to add Multidex or clean and rebuild project or invalidate cache and restart. Try most of the solutions but didn't help.

Comment: Add your BaseApplication class, you don't have enough info here.

Comment: @Booger Please see I've updated the post. TIA.

Comment: Still not enough info, because we can't see the package of the Application class...I would add the full package to the manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in my module-level gradle file. I was used `annotationProcessor` instead of `kapt`.

```
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.40.5'
```

Then changed it into

```
kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.40.5'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your manifest from:

`android:name=".base.BaseApplication"`

to:

`android:name="tech.xyz.android.base.BaseApplication"`

Comment: Tried but didn't work.

Comment: this issue has been resolved. replace `annotationProcessor` with `kapt`